# Create Kotlin multiplatform mobile project from cli

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

How to create a Kotlin multiplatform mobile project via command line in linux?

1. I installed Kotlin command-line compiler (kotlinc).
2. And Gradle build tool.
3. I add gradle and kotlin `bin` directory to my `PATH`.

Now, I would like to create an example multiplatform project. Is there any template I can use to set up the project structure?

For Gradle, I found good [tutorial](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_building_kotlin_applications.html), such as to build CLI applications, but not mobile. On the Kotlin side, I found a nice [tutorial](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-mobile-getting-started.html#next-step) by using the GUI.